# Filter data by multiple criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I need to filter through a data set to find data that matches given criteria within a function

For example:

Example input/output

```
findMyCampsites(campgrounds, 'ocean', 8) //-> [1]
findMyCampsites(campgrounds, 'forest', 4) //-> [18]
findMyCampsites(campgrounds, 'forest', 6) //-> 'Sorry, no campsites with that view are available to host your party'
```

This is the data set I've been given

```
let campgrounds = [
  { number: 1, view: 'ocean', partySize: 8, isReserved: false },
  { number: 5, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 12, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
  { number: 18, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 23, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: true }
];
```

I've tried this

```
function findMyCampsites(campgrounds, location, groupSize) {
  var available = []
  for (var i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++) {
    if (campgrounds[i].isReserved == false && campgrounds[i].view == location) {
      available.push(campgrounds[i].number)
    }
  }
  return available
}
```

My issue is every time I add in the `partySize` variable whether through an `else`/`if` conditional statement or just go right ahead and add in the `else` statement I'm always coming up short on the output and I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

I'm admittedly new to this so I apologize if I'm being unclear ill add screenshots to help with that screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> _**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text."_

Comment: So, if I understand properly, you want to make a function that finds campsites that have the _view_ passed in _location_,  and that the _groupSize_ passed is less or equal than the _partySize_...

Comment: This is my exact objective     [Write a function findMyCampsites. Given a campgrounds array, a type of view as a string, and the party size as a number, return an array with campsite numbers for the matching campsites.]

Comment: Can you explain more ?  `findMyCampsites` function look good to me, based on your expect output.

Comment: the issue im having is when running it with the ocean view it returns the forest site number along with the ocean site numbers and should only return the ocean numbers.

Comment: i am also not able to run it at all with an else statement for unavailable campsite view/partysize combos. im not sure exactly what info you need if you could help me help u  but the gist of it is that when it should give numbers 1 and 5 it gives 1,5,and 18 but when its only required to give 18 it does fineand the instant i add the statement for unavailable campsites it all goes to hell

Comment: `findMyCampsites(_, _, groupSize) ` what `groupSize` do in your function?

Comment: try this: `var findMyCampsites = (view, partySize) => campgrounds.filter(x => !x.isReserved && x.view == view && x.partySize == partySize).map(x => x.number);`  To find only matched value...

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me. Note that you should use `let` instead of `var`.

```js
let campgrounds = [
  { number: 1, view: 'ocean', partySize: 8, isReserved: false },
  { number: 5, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 12, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
  { number: 18, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 23, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: true }
];

function findMyCampsites(location, groupSize)
{
  let available = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++)
  {
    const campground = campgrounds[i];
    if (campground.isReserved == false && campground.view == location && groupSize <= campground.partySize)
    {
      available.push(campground.number)
    }
  }
  return available;
}



// The following is just for the HTML form
let inputs  = document.querySelectorAll('input');
let submit  = document.querySelector('button');
let results = document.querySelector('div#results');
submit.addEventListener('click', function()
{
  let location = inputs[0].value;
  let groupSize = inputs[1].value;
  results.innerHTML += '<p><b>' + location + ',&nbsp;' + groupSize.toString() + '</b>' + '&nbsp;'.repeat(4) + findMyCampsites(location, groupSize) + '</p>\n';
  inputs[0].value = '';
  inputs[1].value = '';
});
```

```html
<input id="location" type="text" placeholder="Location">
<input id="groupSize" type="number" placeholder="Group size">
<button>Find</button>
<div id="results">
  
</div>
```